# Use numpy to read a two-column csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I was curious whether there is a nicer way to do this. I have a csv file with two columns (which is fairly common), for example the 1st column is the time stamp and the second column is the data.

```
# temp.csv
0., 0.
1., 5.
2., 10.
3., 15.
4., 10.
5., 0.
```

And then I want to read this temp.csv file:

```
import numpy as np

my_csv = np.genfromtxt('./temp.csv', delimiter=',')
time = my_csv[:, 0]
data = my_csv[:, 1]
```

This is entirely fine, but I am just curious whether there is a more elegant way to do this, since this is a fairly common practice.

Thank you!

-Shawn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
my_csv = np.genfromtxt('./temp.csv', delimiter=',')
time, data = my_csv.transpose()
```

or the one liner:

```
time, data = np.genfromtxt('./temp.csv', delimiter=',').transpose()
```

or another one liner where `genfromtxt` does the transposition:

```
time, data = np.genfromtxt('./temp.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Are they more elegant? That's up to the reader.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is quite elegant. Warren's answer is great too!

Comment: Quick comment for future readers: I am now using time, data = np.genfromtxt('./temp.csv', delimiter=',').T because I think this is the clearest way :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `unpack` argument to have [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) return the transpose of the array.  Then you can do your assignments like this:

```
In [3]: time, data = genfromtxt('temp.csv', unpack=True, delimiter=',')

In [4]: time
Out[4]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])

In [5]: data
Out[5]: array([  0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  10.,   0.])
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that there is a unpack argument. This is actually what I was wondering!

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas dataframes if you want nice ways for working with csv type tables.'

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html